# Given the permutation $\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 1&2&3&4&5\\ 3&1&2&5&4 \end{array}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the permutation $$\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&2&3&4&5\\
3&1&2&5&4
\end{array}\right)$$
the matrix A is defined to be the one whose $i$-th column of the identity matrix $I$. Which of the following is correct?

1. $A=A^{-2}$
2. $A=A^{-4}$
3. $A=A^{-5}$
4. $A=A^{-1}$

Comment: Most of the question you have asked in MSE are from CSIR JUNE 2014 Question paper. In none of them you have given what you have tried. It seems you need to read lot. Getting the solution alone for this problem wont help you much. Try to read lot of books and solve the exercises in those books. mainly solve the previous year question papers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That permutation has a $3$ cycle and a $2$ cycle. So, you need to apply that permutation $6$ times to get back to the identity, i.e. $A^6 = I$ and $A^k \neq I$ for $1 \le k \le 5$. Thus, $A^{-1} = A^5$.